# jquery totaling time improperly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

So I have the following HTML table on my site

```
<div class="timecard">
<table>
<tr class = "display-even-row">
    <td align="left" style="color:#000099">In</td>
    <td align="left" class="job_code">2400-Duffy's</td>
    <td align="left" class="hrs">00:04</td>
</tr>
<tr class = "display-odd-row">
    <td align="left" style="color:#009900">In</td>
    <td align="left" class="job_code">1500-Orchard</td>
    <td align="left" class="hrs">01:00</td>
</tr>
<tr class = "display-even-row">
    <td align="left" style="color:#000099">In</td>
    <td align="left" class="job_code">32-Black</td>
    <td align="left" class="hrs">10:00</td>
</tr>
<tr class = "display-odd-row">
    <td align="left" style="color:#009900">In</td>
    <td align="left" class="job_code">1500-Orchard</td>
    <td align="left" class="hrs">4</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="total">
</div>
```

And I have the following jquery script to calculate the total hours of each individual job code. It is designed dynamically to allow for more job codes to be added later. However, it is not adding up hours properly, but not displaying if a job has minutes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var timeString = $(this).next('td.hrs').text();
var components = timeString.split(':');
var seconds = components[1] ? parseInt(components[1], 10) : 0;
var hrs = parseInt(components[0], 10) + seconds / 60;
total += hrs;

var temp = [];
$('.job_code').each(function(index, element){
    var text = $(this).text();
    temp.push(text);
});

// remove duplicates
var job_code = [];
$.each(temp, function(index, element){
    if($.inArray(element, job_code) === -1) job_code.push(element);
});

var sum = {};
$.each(job_code, function(index, element){
    var total = 0;
    $('.job_code:contains('+element+')').each(function(key, value){
        total += parseInt($(this).next('td.hrs').text());
        sum[index] = {'job_code' : element, 'total': total};
    });
});

console.log(sum);

$.each(sum, function(index, element){
    $('#total').append('<p>Total for '+element.job_code+': '+element.total+'</p>');
});

});
```

Any thoughts on what changes need to be made to make this work with 00:00 instead of just whole integers? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of using a date/time parsing library, you'll probably want to extract the integer strings on either side of the colon before you attempt to parse them.

```
var timeString = $(this).next('td.hrs').text();
var components = timeString.split(':');
var seconds = components[1] ? parseInt(components[1], 10) : 0;
var hrs = parseInt(components[0], 10) + seconds / 60;
total += hrs;
```

You could also use a regular expression to do this, but the split should work just fine.

Comment: Ok. I've updated my code, but it still isn't displaying .04 hours for Duffy's. But adds the hours correctly. Any more ideas?

Comment: @h3tr1ck i saved one here and ran it http://jsfiddle.net/malectro/8W5be/ . 00:04 shouldn't be .04 hours at base 10, which is why I divided by 60. 0.06666666666666667 hours is correct (albeit long).

Comment: that is now adding double the hours for the other job codes. 00:04 stands for 4 minutes in the table.

Comment: yeah, there was a bad line of code. works here: http://jsfiddle.net/malectro/8W5be/1/